# Print finded data in console, mongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im trying to find data in a MongoDB collection, in C# using the driver. I have this code:

```
var connectionString = "******";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var db = client.GetDatabase("*****");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("*****");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Usuario.inf_qr", "EDF07D93-9C48-4D5D-BE2F-1602B4FFAEE8");
        var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result)
```

When i print result in the console i get System.Collections.Generic.List'[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument] insted of the data that im trying to find.

Thanks for the response.

EDIT: updated

Comment: This might be a ToString problem. Try calling the ToString method when printing. Can you post the Console.Write statement?

Comment: You are not defining which object you wanna print something about in your list. Choose an object like result.bsondoku.name.

Right know you are just printing the object value which is a:

System.Collections.Generic.List'[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining which object you wanna print something about in your list. Choose an object like result.bsondoku.name. Right know you are just printing the object value which is a: System.Collections.Generic.List'[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]

Answer (score 0):

You can `Console.Write` data using `ToJson`, like this:

```
Console.Write(result.ToJson());
```